# Mount Samba share allowing users to read/write

Tags: mount, samba

I mount a samba share with the following command:

```
# mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/username pc -o username=username,password=xxxxx
```

But only root can go inside that share.

How to allow users read/write in the share?

Answer (score 22):

If only one user needs read/write access, you can make them the owner of the mounted directory using the option `uid=<linux_username>`:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/username pc -o uid=<unix_username>,username=username,password=xxxxx
```

---

If more than one user need read/write access, you can create a group, add the users to it:

```
addgroup new_group
adduser user1 new_group
adduser user2 new_group
adduser user3 new_group
```

then mount the share using options `gid`, `file_mode` and `dir_mode`:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/username pc -o gid=new_group,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,username=username,password=xxxxx
```

---

More information: [`mount.cifs` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mount.cifs.8).

Comment: Quick question:  Does SAMBA require FUSE, as sshfs does?

Comment: @earthmeLon No, Samba doesn't require FUSE.

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond with the group idea! I am using that for sure :)